# ng-src attribute of video tag doesn't work

Tags: android, angularjs, video, ionic-framework

I am working on a mobile app, using Ionic framework and I want to play video in a mobile app. I have a list of video's and I am using video tag for playing the video.

ng-src with full path works fine.
But following block of code doesn't work. I have a list of video's and i can't use hardcoded data, I am allowing user to select the video.

```
<video controls>
 <source ng-src="{{src}}">
```

How can I resolve above problem or any alternate method for the same.

Comment: You're going to have to show a lot more code to get a decent answer. See [ask] and [mcve] and then come back and edit your question appropriately.

Comment: Try this example from this [link](https://www.thepolyglotdeveloper.com/2015/01/embed-video-ios-android-ionicframework-app/) it worked for me ... if not i will upload a sample project for you with steps

Answer (score 0):

I solved the issue. URL loading was blocked.
I fixed it using $sce service

```
ng-src="{{trustSrc(videos.link)}}"
```